# Database generic way of achieving Query Result Change Notification

Tags: java, database

We have a use case in which we would like a Java application to know when a result of a SELECT query changes as a consequence of a DML update in a database. On exploration, this seems to be achievable in the Oracle database using Oracle's "[*Query Result Change Notification*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_cqn.htm#ADFNS546)" (at least with some limitations). But changing the datastore to Oracle database is not an option. We are looking for a solution that works with the following databases:

1. PostgreSQL
2. MySQL
3. MS SQL Server

Further exploration reveled that MS SQL Server has "[*Query Notifications*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/working-with-query-notifications?view=sql-server-ver15)" which is similar to Oracle's "*Query Result Change Notification*". PostgreSQL and MySQL equivalents could not be found.

Coming to the question, what could be a (possibly efficient) way to achieve this in PostgreSQL and MySQL databases? Is there any Java library that helps us know when a SELECT query result changes as a consequence of a DML update in a database?

PS: I've tried to provide enough information in the question. In case any information is required, kindly let me know.

Comment: the Postgrees equivalent would be listen/notify

Comment: I don't think you will ever be able to do this from java! The documentation points to PL/SQL or OLE/ODCB specific pages.

Comment: @jokster is right. I came across this great blog about [PostgreSQL LISTEN/NOTIFY](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/07/postgresql-listen-notify/) which notes that _A key limitation of the JDBC driver is that it cannot receive asynchronous notifications and must poll the backend to check if any notifications were issued._

Also, I don't think its similar to "Query Result Change Notification" as *we* would have to think of the logic for sending a notification appropriately which is not the case with "Query Result Change Notification".